# How do I attach a local javadoc folder to a project without an absolute path

Tags: android, javadoc

I am trying to attach the source for android-support-v4 and have followed the instructions from this question:

[How to install javadoc for Android Compatibility Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577190/how-to-install-javadoc-for-android-compatibility-package)

This project is shared on a git repo, so I don't want to checkin a `.classpath` pointing to a local folder.

What is the best way to point to this javadoc on a shared project? I am open to having everyone else generate the javadoc, but I need a way to point to each person's Android SDK directory. A solution that can checked into the repository would be better though.

Is there a variable I can use in the file path pointing to the javadoc folder? I am hoping for something like this: `file:/$ANDROID_SDK_DIR$/extras/android/compatibility/v4/docs/`

**EDIT:**
I found a [comment](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490#c21) on the bug that pertains to an issue with javadocs and android libraries. I created the properties file and I can now see the javadocs in Eclipse, but I still have the same issue. The file contains an absolute path to my own Android SDK directory.

Comment: Perhaps Maven can give you a more elegant way for dependency management (*.jar, *-source.jar and *-javadoc.jar), see example [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1464220800). The pay is you need mavenize your Android project.

Comment: that is indeed an issue that was introduced with ADT 17 and yet not fixed at ADT 19.

Comment: If you look at edit, a solution was implemented in ADT 20 Preview 3, but even this solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that in the new versions of ADT, you have to include a .properties file along with your jar in the `libs` folder. The normal way of changing the .classpath to point to docs/sources does not work in Eclipse with ADT, but this will.

If you have GSON in a file `gson-2.2.2.jar` create `gson-2.2.2.jar.properties` in the same folder

***gson-2.2.2.jar.properties:***

```
src=docs\\gson-2.2.2-sources.jar
doc=docs\\gson-2.2.2-javadoc.jar
```

Then create a `docs` folder inside `libs` and move your sources and javadoc jars into it.

This solves the issue where anything in `/libs` is compiled into your project. Only files in the root are included, so creating a folder for your docs (`/libs/docs`) is a great way to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in this solution, he has a third-party library in a SVN repository and he wants to associate source/javadoc with it locally in Eclipse.

I don't think there is a satisfying solution but you can try.

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property),

hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. This is an Android specific issue with libraries.