# How can I enable javadoc for the Android support library?

Tags: android, javadoc, android-support-library

When using the Android support library for compatibility and try to view the javadoc for, say, `FragmentTransaction`, I get the following error because there is no associated javadoc file:

> android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
>
> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc
>   and hence no Javadoc could be found.

The support library is added under the Android Dependencies item in the project properties, and shows Javadoc location: (None) - non-modifiable as shown below.  Is there any workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543225/android-support-library-v4-getting-the-source-and-attaching-it-to-the-library

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39567524/2855059

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've lashed together a project with android-support-v4.jar just in the Android Dependencies part of the package view. I have a class

```
public class CountriesFragment extends ListFragment {...}
```

and an import of

```
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
```

up above

I created a file `android-support-v4.jar.properties` in the `libs` folder. It contains the lines:

```
doc=c:\\[path-to-android-sdk]\\docs\\reference
src=C:\\[path-to-android-sdk]\\extras\\android\\support\\v4\\src
```

Presumably you'll have to change to un-escaped forward slashes if not using Windows.

Next right-click the project, select refresh, then you'll get javadoc support.  You don't really need the doc entry--the src entry already contains the javadocs.

Comment: This answer is a better reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder

Comment: It's enough to add the `src` line (especially when the `doc` line doesn't point to an existing folder). Also, I would keep a copy of the properties file in the folder `C:\[path-to-android-sdk]\extras\android\support\v4`. I don't know if it will get automatically picked up in new projects, but at least I have a central location to manually pick it up from :)

Comment: Also, this will work even if the support library is in the _Android Private Libraries_ container. You do not need to move it to the _Android Dependencies_ container.

Comment: "Project -> Close project, Project -> Open project" will be enough.

Comment: If your support library is in the library project then this file (.properties) needs to go to that library project not your working project.

Answer (score 6):

**Edited:**
Refer the following post :

[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder)

**Added:**

Under `\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4` directory of your Android SDK installation you will find the sources for `android-support-v4.jar` (i.e. the src directory) and you can create a jar file of the same using [jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Hope it helps :)

**Added:**

Check this post https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/35702/

according to this

Create a file named **android-support-v4.jar.properties** in the **libs** directory of your project and add following line into it.

`src: <relative or absolute path to the source folder (or archive).>`

I tried this solution and it worked for me. Enjoy :)

Comment: Yes, except then the support library will be in the project twice.  It's already in the build path ash shown in the above screen capture.  It seems like this would be a problem.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to wait a bit to see if someone comes up with a more elegant solution.  Unfortunately, this might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:
Go to File Menu-> Open file-> browse your Project directory in workspace -> select the .classpath file openit->

Keep only below entries in this file and remove all others

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="your dir path without space.../extras/android/support /v4/android-support-v4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
 </classpath>
```

Save the file.
then in Eclipse-> Package Explorer ->right click Project -> Android tools -> Fix Project Properties.

This will add all required files to project , if you want to cross check open .classpath file again and check updates in it.

Run the project successfully :)