# Android Support Package documantation

Tags: android, eclipse

In my Android 2.3.3 application i want to use Fragment so I've installed the support package.

I've used this in Eclipse:

```
Right click on my project ---> Android Tool ---> Add Support Library
```

Fragments works fine but they have no code documentation so its very frustrating to develop that way..

How can i add the documentation to my code ?

I've found some questions regarding that issue but since but it does not fit my case since I used the Eclipse option to add the support package

Note: i didn't add the support library jar file - I've installed as mentioned above

Comment: What do you mean by "add the documentation to my code" ? Are you asking for auto-complete, for the support library?

Comment: no, the auto complete inteliscence works... i want that when i'm moving with my mouse over a Class or method - it will show me it description.. for now it says that there are no JavaDocs to the class

Comment: Have you tried the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628439/how-can-i-enable-javadoc-for-the-android-support-library ?

Comment: no that supposed to work with the jar.. i didn't installed it throw the jar

Comment: i don't know what you mean by that, but by doing the above operation, it copies the .jar file to the projects **libs** folder..