# Not able to enable javadoc for Android Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc, android-support-library

I've read the following posts:
[How to attach javadoc or sources to jars in libs folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873152/how-to-attach-javadoc-or-sources-to-jars-in-libs-folder?rq=1)
[How can I enable javadoc for the Android support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628439/how-can-i-enable-javadoc-for-the-android-support-library)

**But the solution specified doesn't work.**

**Before adding the .properties file:**
[image: Before adding the .properties file]

**After adding the .properties file:**
[image: After adding the .properties file]

After adding the .properties file I've refreshed the project, cleaned the project, closed and launched eclipse but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to add the .properties file in the **lib** folder of **appcompat_v7**(which was added automatically)

**After adding the .properties file in the lib folder of appcompat_v7:**
[image: After adding the .properties file in the lib folder of appcompat_v7]

**This popup gave me the clue to add it in the necessary location:**
[image: Clue]

Correct me if am wrong, I think the reason why the solution in the 2<sup>nd</sup> post worked was because in the earlier versions of the ADT(<22.6.1) when you were creating a new application the appcompat_v7 wasn't included.