# Android Private Libraries does not allow modifications to source attachment

Tags: android

I am getting the following error while trying to use the google maps api using googleplayservices in android. 
I have added the google play services library as dependency project and declared it in android manifest also.

Please help me i am unable to proceed and i have done every possible solution I found in stakeoverflow to solve this error.

Error:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Official solution is

> Allow src/doc attachement for 3rd party jars in libs/
>
> Since those jars
>   are added dynamically through a classpath container, the devs cannot
>   set the source path and the javadoc through Eclipse UI (container
>   don't allow editing those). To fix this, and to make sure that both
>   paths are picked up not only by the current project, but also by other
>   projects (if the current project is a library project), the value is
>   set by a file sitting next to the jar file. The file is name after the
>   jar file, adding .properties at the end. For instance foo.jar ->
>   foo.jar.properties It can currently contain 2 properties: src:
>   relative or absolute path to the source folder (or archive). doc:
>   relative or absolute path to the javadoc.

Check following question for more details
[The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Android Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075453/the-jar-of-this-class-file-belongs-to-container-android-dependencies-which-doe)

Comment: Thanks @Ameer, But I am getting this error while adding google-play-services. google play services does not have javadoc, so i cannot add it in the classpath file. Please help me to slove this error. I have tried every answer in stakeoverflow but nothing worked.

Comment: update your googleplayservices library from Android SDK manager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628439/how-can-i-enable-javadoc-for-the-android-support-library/12629379#12629379   have you checked this solution